# Need help understanding how Ninject is getting a Nhibernate SessionFactory instance into a UnitOfWork?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, dependency-injection, ioc-container, ninject

So using some assistance from tutorials I have managed to wire up a Nhibernate session to my repositories and my repositories to my controllers using Ninject.  However, there is one peice of the setup that I am not grasping the "automagic" of what Ninject is doing and was hoping someone could explain.

Below is my **Ninject ModuleRepository** that inherits from NinjectModule that does all the binding.

```
public class ModuleRepository : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        var helper = new NHibernateHelper(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Environment.MachineName].ConnectionString);

        Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToConstant(helper.SessionFactory)
            .InSingletonScope();

        Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>()
            .InRequestScope();
        Bind<ISession>().ToProvider<SessionProvider>()
            .InRequestScope();
        Bind<IRepository<Product>>().To<ProductRepository>();
        Bind<IRepository<Category>>().To<CategoryRepository>();
    }
}
```

Here is the **UnitOfWork class**:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    private readonly ITransaction _transaction;
    public ISession Session { get; private set; }

    public UnitOfWork(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        _sessionFactory = sessionFactory;

        //Open Session
        Session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        Session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Auto;
        _transaction = Session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        if (!_transaction.IsActive)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("There is no active Transaction");
        _transaction.Commit();
    }

    public void Rollback()
    {
        if (_transaction.IsActive)
            _transaction.Rollback();
    }

    //Close open session
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Session.Close();
    }
}
```

So I understand that we are creating a single instance constant instance of the object that creates a Nhibernate SessionFactory.    Below is the SessionProvider class which returns the session from the UnitOfWork object that wraps each unit of work in a transaction.

**SessionProvider**

```
public class SessionProvider : Provider<ISession>
{
    protected override ISession CreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
        var unitOfWork = (UnitOfWork)context.Kernel.Get<IUnitOfWork>();
        return unitOfWork.Session;
    }
}
```

The Repositories take a ISession in their constructor.  But what I am not seeing is how the UnitOfWork.Session is the "session" that gets passed to my repositories?

Any help in understanding this would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binding using:

```
Bind<ISession>().ToProvider<SessionProvider>().InRequestScope();
```

states that it should maintain Request Scope. That means that Ninject will cache all requests for ISession during the entire HttpRequest - so all classes being injected (or explicitly getting an instance) will be using the same instance of the ISession. In your configuration the same goes for the IUnitOfWork.

See [this post](http://kohari.org/2009/03/06/cache-and-collect-lifecycle-management-in-ninject-20/) by Nate Kohari for descriptions of the different scope objects in Ninject.