# Dependency Inject asp.net MVC4 Ninject

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nhibernate, ninject

This is my first project using `Ninject and MVC`, I`m trying to implement.

But I'm getting this error:

> Error activating ISessionFactory
>
> No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.

Activation path:

3. Injection of dependency `ISessionFactory` into parameter session of constructor of type `PersonRepository`
4. Injection of dependency `IPersonRepository` into parameter `personsRepository` of constructor of type `HomeController`
5. Request for `HomeController`

**My Repository :**

```
public class PersonRepository : IPersonRepository
{
    private ISession openSession;
    private ISessionFactory session;

    public PersonRepository(ISessionFactory session)
    {
        this.openSession = session.OpenSession();
        this.session = session;
    }

    public void CreatePerson(Person person)
    {
        openSession = NhibernateUtilities.OpenIfClosed(session, openSession);
        openSession.SaveOrUpdate(person);
    }
```

**My Controller :**

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
    
    private readonly IPersonRepository personsRepository;

    public HomeController(IPersonRepository personsRepository)
    {
        this.personsRepository = personsRepository;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Person test = new Person()
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "teste",
            Surname = "teste",
            Nickname = "teste",
            Age = 25,
            Division = "teste",
            Email = "teste",
            Lane = "teste"
        };

        personsRepository.CreatePerson(test);

        return View();
    }
```

**Global.asax :**

```
public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
{
    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        kernel.Bind<IPersonRepository>().To<PersonRepository>();
        return kernel;
    }

    protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        base.OnApplicationStarted();
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }

}
```

I'm using `Fluent Nhibernate`.

Comment: Where are you setting up your binding for ISession (or is that automatic?) also it doesn't look like you're calling CreateKernel.

Comment: So, ISessionFactory have a repository to bind? It`s from Fluent . I found this Create Kernel in a tutorial, i need to call it somewhere?

Comment: @RodrigoMagalhães `Estou utilizando ISessionFactory no meu repositório, eu preciso dar bind nele?` Translate this line to English.

Answer (score 2):

Ref : [Need help understanding how Ninject is getting a Nhibernate SessionFactory instance into a UnitOfWork?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687355/need-help-understanding-how-ninject-is-getting-a-nhibernate-sessionfactory-insta)

You need to bind the session factory

```
Bind<ISession>().ToProvider<SessionProvider>().InRequestScope();
```

And use ISession in the repo constructor

```
public class PersonRepository : IPersonRepository
{
    private ISession session;

    public PersonRepository(ISession session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }

...
```